# Bug verification: FF 3.5.4. + Secure Login 0.9.3

Tags: browser-addons, firefox

*Just noticed it a few seconds ago (and immediatelly backuped my profile after :)*

Description: Upon deleting history for the past 1 hour, Secure  Login no longer is able to login to any page. Upon going to the list of passwords saved in Firefox options, the list is empty !!

Upon restarting firefox, the list is back there again.

Is this a bug, or is it supposed to scare users like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this, and it looks like a bug to me.

You can report this to the [main site](https://blueimp.net/mozilla/) or directly to [the developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/100849).

Comment: I don't use it at all, I simply installed it for the purpose of verifying your bug.

Comment: Oh. Never mind then. Thanks for the effort (verification) and the site info.